# I have an element that I want to drag around on a grid, but it breaks my existing transforms

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is my XAML:

```
          <Grid>
          <Grid Margin="0,0,20,20" Name="myGrid" Background="#FFFDFDFD" Width="100" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <il:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotate1" Angle="0" />
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="trans1" />
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale1" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
           </Grid>
           </Grid>
```

I'm using two libraries from the Expression SDK (i:System.Windows.Interactivity and il:Microsoft.Expression.Interactions) which allow me to drag elements around the grid really easily and with great performance.

The problem is that these libraries have messed up the animations I have (which use the transforms in the transform group). If I run the animations before I drag the grid, everything works fine. But as soon as I move the grid, the animations no longer work.

I'm really new to this transform stuff (as you can probably imagine), so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by altering the Storyboard.TargetProperty in the XAML. I originally set the Storyboard.TargetProperty to just "ScaleX" or "ScaleY" of the ScaleTransform itself, and it always worked fine - it just would no longer work AFTER I moved the grid. Here is the updated code:

```
       <Storyboard x:Key="sizeAnimation" >
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myGrid"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" 
        To="1" Duration="00:00:0.4" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myGrid"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
        To="1" Duration="00:00:0.4" />
       </Storyboard>
```

The TargetProperty now steps through the Transforms that I have in the TransformGroup in order to get the current value that I need for the animation (the [2] is the index of the Transform that I need to access - which is the ScaleTransform in the original XAML).

Now everything works properly. Hope this helps somebody